# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException'?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have the touchesBegan method, which is being called whenever I touch an object of Circle class. (Subclass of UIView)

So, what I want is, when I touch a circle, which all of them are placed in a NSMutableArray, to be set set as hidden, which works and to be removed from the array. At that point, the compiler throws me this error:

```
2014-12-23 14:07:09.094 Tap them all[986:39194] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 6 beyond bounds [0 .. 5]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105edcf35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001057ccbb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105dc7f33 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 227
    3   Tap them all                        0x0000000104f44fc1 -[ViewController moveCircles] + 81
    4   Foundation                          0x00000001053862b4 __NSFireTimer + 83
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105e44f64 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105e44b25 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1045
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105e07e5d __CFRunLoopRun + 1901
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105e07486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    9   GraphicsServices                    0x0000000108db79f0 GSEventRunModal + 161
    10  UIKit                               0x00000001062c9420 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    11  Tap them all                        0x0000000104f45e53 main + 115
    12  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000109a9a145 start + 1
    13  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Why is this happening?
Thanks in advance!

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    int k = 0;
    while (k < array.count) {
        if ([touch view] == array[k]) {
            [array[k] setHidden:YES];
            [array removeObjectAtIndex:k];

            break;
        }

        k++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably it is not throwing exception at this point.
It might be in the method 'moveCircles'.

Comment: The problem is in `moveCircles` method, add that method code here. It seems you are trying to access an object from array, and that object index is more than the array bounds. Please provide that method code to dig in.

Comment: You are both right! I was trying to access the array's contents after they were removed.. Thanks guys!!!